# How to fix 'Package org.slf4j is declared in module slf4j.api but module [ModuleName] does not read it'?

Tags: java, logging, logback, slf4j

I'm trying to add logging to my multimodule project using slf4j and logback.
The project has three pom.xml files, one in the model module, one in the view module and one main pom.xml file.
I've added the following dependecies to each of the files:

```
             <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.5</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.13</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.13</version>
            </dependency>
```

Followingly, I placed logback.xml file in the resources folder (available only in the view module) and configured it like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<configuration debug="true">
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} {%thread} %-5level %logger{36} - %msg %n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="FILE"
              class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>${FILE_LOG_PATTERN}</pattern>
        </encoder>
        <file>${LOG_FILE}</file>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <cleanHistoryOnStart>${LOG_FILE_CLEAN_HISTORY_ON_START:-false}</cleanHistoryOnStart>
            <fileNamePattern>${LOG_FILE}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.gz</fileNamePattern>
            <maxFileSize>${LOG_FILE_MAX_SIZE:-10MB}</maxFileSize>
            <maxHistory>${LOG_FILE_MAX_HISTORY:-7}</maxHistory>
            <totalSizeCap>${LOG_FILE_TOTAL_SIZE_CAP:-0}</totalSizeCap>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>

    <logger name="pl.compprog.gui" level="debug"/>
    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Everything seemed to be fine, but I get the 'package org.slf4j is declared in module slf4j.api but module View does not read it' when I try to `import org.slf4j.Logger;`. How to fix this?

I tried to install project from the Maven level, but it does not change anything, although it ends successfully.

Comment: Do you have any `module-info.java` files? Also, why not use Logback `1.2.3` and SLF4J `1.7.26`?

Comment: Ok, I see, I didn't declare slf4j.api as required in module-info.java